# Which path should I take during Episode 3?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I just started Final Fantasy XIII-2 and I am trying to figure out what path I should take now that I just got pass the first boss. Should I:

- Defeat Caius the first time?
- Defeat the Royal Ripeness with Snow?

I'm not trying to get the alternative endings: I've had trouble on both fights in the main storyline and could use advice on which way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your comments correctly, it appears you're at the start of Episode 3, where the main story diverges into two paths:

- **Path 1 (Episode 3, Part 1):** You went to *Yaschas Massif -010 AF-*, then to *Oerba -200 AF-*, and now you have a boss fight with Caius.
- **Path 2 (Episode 3, Part 2):** You went to *Sunleth Waterscape -300 AF-* and met Snow.

Either path is viable and will require you to complete the other when you're finished: the strategy guide claims the second path is the harder one, but I found both to be about the same difficulty in my play-through.

#### Path 1 (Episode 3, Part 1)

The first fight with Caius is supposed to be a push-over: it's merely there to introduce him as an antagonist; he's toying with you.

If you're having difficulty taking him out, you're likely way too low level. Consider going back to earlier areas and completing fragment quests: getting all the fragments I could find and completing the first part of the *Sunleth Waterscape -300 AF-* (to the point where you get Moogle Throw) was more than enough to defeat him with a 5-star rating.

#### Path 2 (Episode 3, Part 2)

If you're trying to defeat the Royal Ripeness immediately after meeting Snow, you're going to have a bad time. Defeating it right after meeting Snow is an alternative route that you will not be able to complete until you're a bit more powerful (in the 2,000+ HP range).

Instead, follow Noel and Snow's advice, give the Royal Ripeness a wide berth, and head to the southern end of the map to complete the main storyline objectives.